# Proxy settings on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, proxy

I'm looking for the proxy settings on Ubuntu Server 18.04.

I found them in regular Ubuntu under `/etc/apt/apt.conf/proxy`, but the apt.conf folder is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the information regarding the proxy configuration in this [link](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-the-proxy-for-apt-for-ubuntu-18-04/)

The instructions are:

Create a new configuration file named proxy.conf.

```
sudo touch /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf
```

Open the proxy.conf file in a text editor.

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf
```

Add the following line to set your HTTP proxy.

> Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:password@proxy.server:port/";

Add the following line to set your HTTPS proxy.

> Acquire::https::Proxy "http://user:password@proxy.server:port/";

Save your changes and exit the text editor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf` and add something like:

`Acquire::http::Proxy "http://...:port/";`

`Acquire::https::Proxy "http://...:port/";`